# Deny Assignment in Azure Databricks - how do I get around this to access storage container?

Tags: azure-databricks

The client """ has permission to
perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action'
on scope '/my/storage/account'; however,
the access is denied because of the deny assignment
with name 'System deny assignment created by
Azure Databricks .....'

What do I need to do to resolve this issue. I successfully loaded a file to the storage container but cannot access it from a python notebook. Here's the error from the notebook.

"shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

It appears the "Deny assignment" issue above is the cause? How can I resolve it. Appreciate your help.

I was expecting to be able to access file from a python notebook with
"%fs ls /mnt/...." but the command failed.

Comment: Are you trying to mount a storage account that is created together with Azure Databricks workspace? Can you post exact error - what I see - it doesn't mention deny assignment

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while reading a file from an ADLS account, as shown below:

[image]

The error is related to authorization. To resolve the issue, I followed the procedure below:

I mounted the ADLS account with Access Key authorization. To obtain the Access Key of the ADLS account, go to the Storage account, click on Access Keys, then click the Show button and copy the Access Key, as shown below:

[image]

I used the following code to mount the ADLS account:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountPointName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<accesskey>"  
  }
)
```

[image]

I accessed the file from the ADLS account using the code below:

```
df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/files/<directory>/<fileName>")
df.show()
```

The data was retrieved, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - In my case the file is already loaded and mounted and I am trying to access it but getting the stated errors.

Comment: could you please provide the code which you used to mount ADLS account?